# Vectorizing slow code in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I have been trying to vectorize this code for a while, but have been unable to. Can someone help please.

```
    %X -[153600x400]
    %W -[153600x500]
    %beta=error=scalar
    %errvals=[40x1]
    %n=400
    iter = 1;
    for ii = 1:n 
        disp(ii);
        x = X(:,ii);
        y = W'*x;        
        W = beta*x*y' + W - beta*W*tril(y*y');       
        beta = options.rate*options.annealfunc(iter);       
        err = err + sum((x - W*(W'*x)).^2);
        errvals(iter) = err/iter;       
        if (any(~isfinite(W)))
            warning(sprintf('Lost convergence at iterator %i; lower learning rate?', niter));
            success = 11;
            break;
        end;       
        if (options.printerr == 1)
            fprintf('Error = %d; Iteration = %i\n', err/iter, iter);
        end;        
        iter = iter+1;
    end;
```

Comment: @Divakar please check now.

Comment: You could indicate on which lines you spent the most time. You can do this using MATLAB profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorization is no "magic" suddenly improving the performance, it basically cuts away the overhead for function calls and iteration. In your case, a loop with 400 iterations and only some function calls, the overhead is minimal. 
Without actually running your code because I don't have all inputs (at least `options.annealfunc` is missing) **I would guess that most of the time is spend performing the matrix multiplications. The right way to improve the performance of matrix multiplications is running them on a GPU.** Assuming you have a compatible graphic card and a license for the distributed computing toolbox, you have to convert your arrays to `gpuArrays`

Comment: >> X=[2 2 2 2];
>> G = gpuArray(X);
There is a problem with the CUDA driver or with this GPU device. Be sure that you have a supported GPU and that the latest driver is installed.

`Caused by:
    The CUDA driver could not be loaded. The library name used was 'nvcuda.dll'. The error was:
    The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: I haven't worked on GPU arrays at all. But I try and get hold of another computer. Can you an example difference in performance btw GPU and processor core.

Comment: Probably the driver is missing or the PC does not have a nvidia graphics card at all.

Comment: My graphic card is of AMD, is there support for that? My driver is upto date.

Comment: Matlab uses CUDA, which is available only for nvidia. If getting a nvidia graphics card is no option, you may switch to a solution using OpenCL. This could be a reimplementation of your code in numpy/pyOpenCL or a c++ implementation which you could mex to use it in matlab.

Comment: Please check this question, as an extension of your answer.

Comment: Your recent question is a totally different problem. Instead of some large matrix multiplications, it includes many small vector products. Nothing to run on a GPU.